# HP DL360 G4 screen resolution problem

Tags: 11.10, server, screen

I just bought an old blade server to mess about with at home and cant get the thing to work. I have run the installer 11.10 x64 server and that was fine.

After installing and rebooting, POST is fine but when grub kicks in the screen shows a popup type box complaining that it cant use the resolution. I have tried different screens and its always the same.

I can reboot and go back into the installer and the screen is fine.

I tried to follow some guides on-line about changing the resolution but I cant get a terminal. I found one in the installer but that is using the ram as /. the installer says 'the drive is mounted as "/target"' but I don't see that, nor /mnt/target.

Could anyone help me configure this and get it running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*(OP stated issue resolved)*

Turns out it was only stuck at grub and just hitting return carried on the boot process.